# Promise resolve() called but does not resolve until loop it was called from terminates

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm writing an application in nodejs based around a game loop. Each iteration of the loop, it fires an event emitter, and calls an update method like so:

```js
  updateLoop() {
    while (!this.windowShouldClose()) {
      this.onUpdate.emit();
      this.update();
    }
  }
```

It seemed like the event emitter could help to write async functions on game objects that wait frame(s) between different operations, much like a coroutine. I wrote a utility function that would call back, or resolve a promise on the next emit of the event emitter:

```js
nextFrame() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.onUpdate.once(resolve); // event emitter will resolve promise on next emit()
  })
}

nextFrameCallback(callback) {
  this.onUpdate.once(callback);
}

// example use
async doThingsAsync() {
  // do something
  await this.nextFrame();
  // do something else on the next frame / loop iteration
}
```

While the callback-based function works as intended, the promise version of nextFrame() does not resolve the promise at the time I would expect. `await nextFrame()` only resolves in my example once the outer loop of `updateLoop()` has exited. I attatched a console.log to the promise to find out more, and found that the console log and resolve() do get called within the loop, but awaiting it will still wait for the loop to fully terminate.

```js
nextFrameDebug() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.onUpdate.once(() => {
      console.log('debug nextFrame'); // this prints during the expected loop iteration
      resolve(); // this does not actually resolve until updateLoop() terminates
    })
  })
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle demonstrating the functions above: https://jsfiddle.net/8L4wub29/5/
It seems as if I am close to a functional solution, but there is something I'm misunderstanding about promises or async functions. Does this have to do with calling the async function from within a loop? How could I write nextFrame() so that the promise resolves on the next iteration of the loop, instead of after the loop exits? I realize that for most functionality in a game, timeouts with milliseconds are more useful, but there may be some cases like waiting for physics updates where a game might want to wait just one frame as a utility function. The callback-based version works fine, but if you need to use it multiple times then you need to nest it, which does not look as clean as using `await`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using native `async` functions for your `onUpdate` function? You should only ever use `Promise` directly to adapt older APIs that predate `Promise` (such as `window.setTimeout`) or for stubbing/testing. Promises should not be used to represent repeatable events. For that, consider using [RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/) instead (RxJS is completely unrelated to ReactJS, bte).

Comment: I'm calling into a node-addon-api C library to do graphics/rendering in this app, and its API will wait the remaining duration of a frame after drawing is finished automatically, which I assume is all happening synchronously.

Comment: "and its API will wait the remaining duration of a frame after drawing is finished automatically" - uhhh, that sounds _horrible_ (as in JS, _nothing_ should "wait" or block a thread). It's possible you're misusing the library. Please tell us more about what you're doing.

Comment: I'm still working on writing the binding, so it's a little sparse with documentation. https://github.com/twuky/raylib-4.0 is the repo for it. between the BeginDrawing() and EndDrawing() calls always seem to take up the duration of one frame, whatever the target FPS is sent to, as far as I understand it.
What it sounds like to me is you are suggesting that the main update loop itself be an async function, which may be possible to do, if that loop just updates game logic, then the draw calls could all happen synchronously elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises come with a guarantee that their `.then` callback will *always* be called asynchronously. This means that if you have some random promise, and you do something like this:

```
somePromise.then(() => {
  console.log('inside');
});
console.log('outside');
```

You will consistently see "outside" followed by "inside", even if the promise happens to already be in the resolved state. Promises were designed this way so you can be sure of the order of execution, and thus not have to fix painful bugs involving both orders. Same goes when you use `await` instead of explicit `.then`'s: the code after the `await` must wait until the promise resolves, and also that the call stack returns to system code.

So when you switched from callbacks to promises, you went from code that could synchronously call the callback in the middle of the loop, to code which must wait for execution to return. Only once `updateLoop` returns or yields can the code after the promise run. Since that loop never returns or yields until it's all over, the promises all get delayed until after the loop.

If you need the `updateLoop` to run synchronously, then you can not use promises for this. If instead `updateLoop` is supposed to be asynchronous (maybe setting timeouts before running the next step), then promises can be used, but i'll need more details on what you're trying to do to give an example.

Comment: This explanation makes sense to me. It sounds like with my specific use case where the render step is waiting synchronously, any routine-like behavior that takes multiple "frames" would need to be callback-based to function. My main goal with the promise approach was just to use the await syntax for cleaner functions

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I found something that provides the intended functionality. I simply updated the updateLoop() call in the example to this.

```js
  async updateLoop() {
    while (!this.windowShouldClose()) {
      await null;
      this.onUpdate.emit();
      this.update();
    }
  }
```

Would somebody be able to comment with more clarification why this now produces the intended effect? Changing the function to async does not impact the point at which the promise resolves unless I add an await statement. My assumption that is including an await statement frees the event loop which finally allows the promise to resolve.
If you edit the above JSfiddle with this function, the numbers printed in the console won't coincide with what the print statements "expect" - that only has to do with then the counter is incremented. The execution order appears to be correct.

Comment: When code execution hits an `await`, the function then returns a promise (if this is the first await) or yields otherwise. Either way, code execution stops, which gives other code a chance to run. This idea of yours does indeed work. /thumbsup